# Fetching contact no crashes when there is no phone no assigned to the contact

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact

I am trying to read the contact phone no. The below code works fine if the number is available but if there are no phone no assigned to the contact , it is crashing. Can Anu let me know how to handle this.

```
((currentContact.phoneNumbers.first?.value)! as CNPhoneNumber).stringValue
```

Comment: You should see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should learn about optional values in Swift...

```
if let contactPhoneNumber = currentContact.phoneNumbers.first?.value?.stringValue {
    // do something with the value
} 
else {
    // the value isn't there 
}
```

Comment: No problem! Optionals are paramount to using Swift though so if you don't understand this (optional chaining and if...let) I highly suggest looking more deeply into the literature.